# Javascript Classes objects recurring

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I am creating a few classes to model an election... I have area and candidates and parties

````
class Party {
    constructor(name) {
        this.partyName = name
        this.candidates = []
    }

    toString() {
        const result = `This is the ${this.partyName} party`
        return result
    }

    fetchCandidates() {
        let result = ``
        this.candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
            result += candidate.name
        })
    }
    registerCandidate(candidate) {
        let state = true;
        this.candidates.forEach((obj) => {
            if (candidate.name == obj.name) {
               state = false;
            }
        })
        if (state) {
            this.candidates.push(candidate)
        }
    }
    registerAllCandidates() {
        this.candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
            candidate.area.candidates.push(candidate)
        })
    }
}

class ElectorateArea {
    constructor(electorateArea) {
        this.name = electorateArea
        this.specialAreas = []
        this.candidates = []
    }

    fetchSpecialAreas() {
        let result = ``
        this.specialAreas.forEach((obj) => {
            result += obj.areaName
        })
        return result
    }

    fetchCandidateNames() {
        let result = []
        this.candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
            result.push(candidate.fullName)
        })
        return result
    }

    registerSpecialArea(specialArea) {
        let state = true;
        this.specialAreas.forEach((obj) => {
            if (specialArea.areaName == obj.areaName) {
                state = false;
            }
        })
        if (state) {
            this.specialAreas.push(specialArea)
        }
    } ```


```     let candidate1 = new Candidate('James', 'Shaw', Object.assign({}, wellingtonCentral))
    let wellingtonCentral = new ElectorateArea('Auckland Central')
````

Hi I have these classes of Area, and Candiate Area has a list of candidates specific to the area and each candidate it initialized with a reference to their area.
How come in the image the candidate and area objects are so many?
[image: Recurring candidate and area objects]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the Candidate class in the question -also, the second last line of the code you posted would throw an error regardless of whatever Candidate class looks like

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry there is a lot to post but I think the error is here registerAllCandidates() {
        this.candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
            candidate.area.candidates.push(candidate)
        })
    }

Comment: Class Candidate { constructor(firstName, lastName, area) {
        this.fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName
        this.votes = []
        this.area = area
    } }

Comment: *"How come in the image the candidate and area objects are so many?"* because you have an `Array` of them. One such `Array` is evident in the `class Party` where you have  `this.candidates = []`. There is no output error. That is the real structure of your data.

Comment: Oh derp so it is fine but im just checking the structure over and over? @ChukwujiobiCanon

Comment: Yes. You recursively un-nested the data.

Comment: Do i have an infinite amount of areas and candidates?? because of registerAllCandidates or just one area with candidate in it @ChukwujiobiCanon

Comment: I doubt that. It will have an end but the data is definitely complex.

Comment: "*Do i have an infinite amount of areas and candidates?*" - no. It's the very same two objects over and over. They just reference each other. It's `registerAllCandidates` causing this.

Comment: So if it is the same actual object just referencing eachother over and over is that fine? would this cause problems with space/time complexity? @Bergi

Comment: @HectorHarris Yes, that's totally fine, constant space. It's only you expanding them over and over. And don't write an algorithm that recursively traverses them without bounds.

Comment: Please provide the full code with Candidate class and initializing (settings "data").

Comment: This looks like a design/architecture flaw to me...  why would every candidate have an area, that has candidates, that have areas, that have candidates... until infinity and beyond? I suggest just giving each candidate an area id (and nothing nested), and give each area an array of candidate ids (and nothing nested).

Comment: @Kokodoko Hi, using ids seems like a good alternative. My thinking was that as each area has different candidates I should register the candidates with that given area as an attribute so that they can easily be associated. As they are just referencing eachother over and over and it is not actually creating new objects I dont think theres anything wrong with how things are structured.